# PhpED How to jump in an instance to Favourite File

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phped

I have a file in my project I frequently need to open, and I am forever looking for it. OK, I can usually find it via `Ctrl + Tab` (as it was recently accessed) or via the drop-down menu right of the file tabs, or via `Ctrl + Shift + N` to search for the file by name, but all of these take too long.

A Global bookmark would be awesome or a 'favourite files' tab I could float... does anything like that exist? I tried floating the file itself as well as adding it to a 'New Tab Group' (both can be done by right-clicking the file tab), but both of these options take up valuable space - you cannot have the file auto-hide in the way unpinned tabs do.

Does anyone have a trick up their sleeve?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little on the nose and not the perfect "global bookmark" solution sought, but renaming the file so that it appears at the top of the drop-down tab list is half a solution. The file is still two clicks away - one would be better.